# Actializar elementos de tabla que no son input

Tags: javascript, html, div, table, refresh

¿Es posible refrescar una tabla que esta dentro de un *div* para que todos los demás datos no se modifiquen? ya que es un formulario.

La tabla se modifica desde otra ventana emergente, pero se busca que al darle al botón actualizar guarde la nueva información y la tabla muestre los nuevos datos.

```html
    <div id="tabala"> <table width="90%" align='center' border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="smallBoldBoxLeft">Lugar de Nacimiento: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4"  class="smallBox"><? echo $rowedo['cnombre']; ?></td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>  
       <td colspan="2" class="smallBoldBoxLeft">Domicilio:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="4" class="smallBox"><? echo $domicilio; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
       <td colspan="2" class="smallBoldBoxLeft">Tel&eacute;fono:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="2" name="etelefono1" class="smallBox"> <? echo $row2['eptelefono1'] ?> </td>
       <td colspan="2" name="ctelefono" class="smallBox"><? echo $row2['cptelefono'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
       <td colspan="2" class="smallBoldBoxLeft">Tel&eacute;fono2:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="2" name="etelefono2" class="smallBox"><? echo $row2['eptelefono2']?></td>
    </tr> </table> <div>
```

Anteriormente hice un ejemplo, pero era actualizar únicamente un *input* con un botón

```
 <input type="button" value="Recargar" onclick="recargar()"/>
```

y la funcion

```
function recargar(){
  document.getElementById("caja").innerHTML = "Contenido nuevo";  }
```

Ya intenté modificando la función

```
function recargar(){
  document.getElementById("caja").innerHTML = document.getElementById("caja");  }
```

Pero solo se actualizan si son tipo *input*

Comment: esto no es php es javascript

Comment: Bienvenid**e** a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta ¿[ask]?. Si pones la etiqueta [tag:php] presumo que te interesa que el servidor te devuelva **la sustancia** para actualizar la tabla cuando se **pinche el button**. ¿Entendí bien?

Comment: quevedo, si es exactamente eso, sol he realizado el ejercicio con un input y es donde me surge el problema con la tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes poner ID a las celdas (TD) que quieras actualizar, o bien, obtener primero el div, desde ahí la tabla, fila y celda a actualizar. Mucho más fácil la primera opción.

```js
// Estos datos son solo para el ejemplo,
// los debes tomar de tu formulario como haces normalmente
let lugarNac = 'Alguna ciudad';
let domicilio = 'Calle y número';

// Asignar evento a botón
document.querySelector('#actualiza').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Remplazar contenido por ID
    document.querySelector('#cnombre').innerText = lugarNac;
    // Remplazar buscando div, tabla
    document.querySelector('#tabala table')
        .rows[1]  // Segunda fila
        .cells[1] // Segunda celda
        .innerText = domicilio; // Nuevo valor
});
```

```html
<div id="tabala">
  <table width="90%" align='center' border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="smallBoldBoxLeft">Lugar de Nacimiento: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td colspan="4"  class="smallBox" id="cnombre">Valor inicial</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>  
       <td colspan="2" class="smallBoldBoxLeft">Domicilio:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="4" class="smallBox">Valor inicial</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
       <td colspan="2" class="smallBoldBoxLeft">Tel&eacute;fono:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="2" name="etelefono1" class="smallBox">123456</td>
       <td colspan="2" name="ctelefono" class="smallBox">123</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>  
       <td colspan="2" class="smallBoldBoxLeft">Tel&eacute;fono2:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="4" name="etelefono2" class="smallBox">9876543</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
<button id="actualiza">Actualizar</button>
```

**Notas:**

- Con ID solo necesitas una pequeña modificación en el HTML en cada celda que requieras actualizar
- Buscando por tabla, fila y columna, el código es más largo, más difícil de leer y, principalmente, más difícil de mantener porque cualquier cambio en el HTML de la tabla podría hacer que deje de funcionar

Comment: muchísimas gracias, con eso ya me aclare y pude realizarlo :)

Comment: Si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, para que otros usuarios con un problema similar puedan identifiquen que es útil.

Comment: listo, gracias por el aviso soy algo nuevo en esto